# exception during spring time change(DST) in where clause

Tags: oracle, dst, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a table which has column with data type as "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE"

Problem:
For the below query I get exception which says time zones does not exists.

```
select * from table where update_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-3/24;
```

Exception occurs during one hour window of  spring time change. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce on my environment, but I think the error is caused by the casting of a `DATE` datatype to an invalid `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.

For instance in the `Europe/Paris` time zone, the timestamp `2014-03-30 02:30:00` is invalid:

```
SQL> SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2014-03-30 02:30 Europe/Paris',
  2                         'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi TZR')
  3    FROM dual;
SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2014-03-30 02:30 Europe/Paris',
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
```

This time and day does not exist since the clocks are forwarded between `02:00` and `03:00`.

Since your right hand side of the `<=` operator is a date ([adding a timestamp and a number produces a date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50990)) and you compare it to a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`, it gets casted to the datatype of the column.

I think using interval arithmetics will solve the issue since this will be converted to a valid timestamp. As an added benefit, the resulting code will be easier to read.

Can you try:

```
select * from table where update_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3' HOUR;
```

Comment: Hi,Error perists with the suggestion which you had given. i tried something like this SELECT *
FROM dual
WHERE current_timestamp > to_timestamp('03-12-2014 02:30','MM-DD-YYYY hh:mi') - INTERVAL '3' DAY; i get below error  ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"
*Cause:    The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.
*Action:   Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval.

Comment: Stop comparing `TIMESTAMP` with `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Use `to_timestamp_tz` instead of `to_timestamp`, **just like I did in my answer**. Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Sorry for late response.It worked with to_timestamp_tz